# What cards are the Horsemen referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me

In the last scene of [*Now You See Me*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1670345/), when the *Four Horsemen* go to the park, *Henley Reeves* asks whether they have the cards.

**Edit**

I'm asking about [this scene](https://vimeo.com/74585381). Does it mean that Dylan Rhodes isn't the one giving them the cards? What's the point of that scene? it's confusing

Comment: That scene is from the _extended cut_ on the DVD, and [according to the director](http://www.comingsoon.net/news/movienews.php?id=108241): _"...the beginning of the sequel"_ - The locked crates probably contain the stuff the they need for their next job, and to open them they need _cards_.

Comment: @Oliver_C so that scene doesn't mean anything right? at least not yet

Answer (score 4):

What we see in that scene is basically a bit of **a funny setup for a possible sequel that doesn't really have much bearing on the actual plot** and only tries to end the movie with a notion of *"On to new adventures!"* and wasn't part of the theatrical release (as pointed out by *Oliver_C* in his comment and as Louis Leterrier [confirmed in an interview](http://www.comingsoon.net/movies/features/108241-following-up-with-now-you-see-me-director-louis-leterrier)).

To recap it a bit again, it puts the Horsemen into a new location where they find crates containing what is supposedly their gear for the next job. When posed with the question how to open those crates,

> **Henley:** Guys, the cards.
>   **Merrit:** Wha...What card?
>   **Daniel:** Sorry, what do you mean, "what card"?
>   **Merrit:** *(fumbling in his pockets)*...Okay.

So the point here is that Henley seems to be referring to **the [tarot cards each of the Horsemen got](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13502/49) as their invitation at the beginning of the movie**, and which were later used in the tree at the end when they met Dylan Rhodes (or rather Lyonel Shrike's son). The joke here is, that Merrit actually forgot to bring his card. There is not really anything more to it. Those cards served as their access into *The Eye* throughout the entire movie and are likely used in a similar way in further tasks and interactions with *The Eye*, like accessing the crates with the gear for their next show/adventure. You could say they're somewhat like the Horsemen's ID cards inside the organization of *The Eye*.

Comment: that's not what i meant sir, i'll upload the scene that i want to ask about (hopefully it's not illegal, only 1 min long and I'll edit my question)

Comment: please read my edit

Comment: These are actually the cards you're asking about - if you note in this scene each of the flight cases have the associated eye from the tarot card set given out at the start of the movie.

Comment: @Lynob I updated the answer to adress your updated question a bit more specifically.

Answer (score 2):

The final instructions the Horsemen receive are to go to the park. There they find the card-tree of Lionel Shrike, featuring the King of Spades/Swords.

> You need five cards for a Tarot reading. The five cards are in order of appearance: King of Spades/Swords, Lovers, Hermit, High Preistess [sic], Death. - [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/NowYouSeeMe)

So when they saw the fifth card (they had the four cards delivered to them a year back), they knew the reading was complete. To read, they now needed all five cards together. That's what they were referring to.

The King of Spades/Swords is the card referring to the man with the "idea" - their benefactor. Who taught them magic and made them into the Four Horsemen.

Comment: that's not what i meant sir, i'll upload the scene that i want to ask about (hopefully it's not illegal, only 1 min long and I'll edit my question)

Comment: please read my edit